# echo const from included php file

Tags: php

I have a file called "config.php" that looks like this:

```
define("DB_NAME", "mydatabase")
```

in another file I have:

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', 'C:'.DS.'inetpub'.DS.'wwwroot');
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'lib');

require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');
echo DB_NAME;
```

which outputs :
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lib\initialize.php on line 27

If it helps at all this a new installation of php. PHP is working but there may be something I missed in the php.ini. 
I no there's just some small thing I'm missing but I can't figure it out. Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: this works fine for me.. are you sure the file has actually been included?

Comment: If you need an absolute path to that configuration file, you should try `dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php'` in your initialize.php.

Comment: Nevermind I I figured it out. Forgot to add "php" after the "<?" in config.php

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest that instead of using a ternary statement for a 1 line solution you did this...

```
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

It's much more readable.